# Formatting a float value

Tags: objective-c, timestamp

In my IPhone App Development, I'm using a timestamp value for an order id value.

I want to format the timestamp value in such a way that it contains only decimal value.

Like

timestamp value= 343434234.78900633

Now I want to format that time stamp value, so that it returns the decimal value 78900633.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`modf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/modf/) function that breaks a double/float into an int an a fraction.

```
double intpart;
double param = 343434234.78900633;
double fractpart = modf (param , &intpart);
printf ("%lf = %lf + %lf \n", param, intpart, fractpart);

char buf[32];
sprintf(buf, "%f", fractpart);
int fpart = atoi(buf+2);
printf("Fractional as int = %d\n", fpart);
```

Comment: @prasad1250 Good point - I edited the answer; it should be a `double`.

Comment: Thanx very much.

But, what value should I specify for intpart.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  The fractional part has a variable number of significant digits.  If the time were 343434234.27, would you want 27 or 27000000 or what?  Are you just looking for the number of nanoseconds or something?

Comment: well, i just need the fractional part for a given time stamp value.

Comment: @prasad1250 Since it's a fractional part, you can add as many zeros as you please: `1.78900633` is the same as `1.7890063300000`, but of course `78900633` is not the same as `7890063300000`. If you need, say, 10 digits, simply multiply the fraction by `10000000000` (ten to the power that is equal the number of digits you want), and assign the result to an integral (`int` or `long long`) variable.

Comment: Heyy.I think u didn't got my problem..I'm not worried about the number of digits in the fractional part . Suppose, I have a value 4567.8989898, so my output should be 8989898 (any no of digits). Right now, i'm getting value something like .8989898.

Comment: @prasad1250 It does not make much sense to produce a number like that, because the results cannot be even compared directly without reinterpretation (e.g. `0.95` becomes `95`, while `0.10003` becomes `10003`, i.e. a smaller number becomes much bigger after the transformation). If you insist on making it happen, take a look at the edit, it should do the trick.